# equivalence of functors categories

Tags: category-theory

Let a functor $F:C\rightarrow D$ and denote the category $\Delta^1$ as the poset $0<1$. I'm trying to prove that if the induced functor of $F$ on

$\hat F :Fun(\Delta^1,C)^\cong\rightarrow Fun(\Delta^1,D)^\cong$

is a category equivalence, then $F$ is also an equivalence

It's easy to show that $F$ is essentially surjective: for object $X \in D$, look at 
$Id_X\in Fun(\Delta^1,D)^\cong$.  there is a functor $g\in Fun(\Delta^1,C)^\cong$, s.t. $\hat F g\cong Id_x$. Then $g$ must be an identity for some object $Y$, and so $FY\cong X$.

But I didn't manage to show fully-faithfullnes. I tried to create a bijection backward from objects in $\hat F$ to morphisms in $F$, but that didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathrm{Fun}(\Delta^1,C)^\cong$? The full subcategory of $\mathrm{Fun}(\Delta^1,C)$ spanned by those $f:\Delta^1\to C$ such that $f(0\to 1)$ is an isomorphism?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$C$ and $D$ embed fully faithfully in the functor categories via constant functors, and their images are preserved by $\hat F$.